# setup workspace for bizapps-dev-box

Tags: installation, workspace

How to set up a workspace for bizapps-dev-box and reference in a common way across macOS, Windows and Linux

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal

```
$ cd $HOME
$ mkdir -p $HOME/workspace
$ cd $HOME/workspace
$ git clone <repo_url>
$ cd <repo_url>
```

Spike Test: For querying from the Terminal